# get all inner brackets/parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, string, brackets

I'm working on getting all inner parentheses of a string in JavaScript.

For example if I have a string like that (don't bother about % signs, Qx values are surrounded with it)

```
((!%Q1% || %Q2%) || ((%Q3% && %Q4%) || (%Q5% && %Q6%)))
```

I would like to get in my result:

```
(!%Q1% || %Q2%) || ((%Q3% && %Q4%) || (%Q5% && %Q6%))
(!%Q1% || %Q2%) 
(%Q3% && %Q4%) || (%Q5% && %Q6%)
(%Q3% && %Q4%)
(%Q5% && %Q6%)
```

Basically I'm looking for some universal way, not only for example above. I was trying to do so using something like that in loops, but it was working only for much simpler examples (with less parentheses)

```
init = condition.indexOf('(');
fin = condition.lastIndexOf(')');
inner = condition.substr(init+1,fin-init-1);
```

I would like to use only JS, but other solutions are welcome.

Comment: Use or write a parser. JS regex won't do.

Comment: Speaking of parsers: http://pegjs.org/ or https://zaach.github.io/jison/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code from [Sean's comment at *Matching Nested Constructs in JavaScript, Part 2* blog](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-match-recursive-regexp), just you will have to add `(` and `)` at the end of the matches as they will get stripped off:

```js
function matchRecursiveRegExp (str, left, right, flags) {
 var str_copy = str,
 f = flags || "",
 g = f.indexOf("g") > -1,
 x = new RegExp(left + "|" + right, "g" + f.replace(/g/g, "")),
 l = new RegExp(left, f.replace(/g/g, "")),
 a = [],
 b = [],
 keep_going, t, s, m;
 do {
   t = 0;
   keep_going = false;
   while (m = x.exec(str_copy))
   {
     if (l.test(m[0])) {
       if (!t++) {
         s = x.lastIndex;
       } else {
         //another start has occurred, save that off
         b.push(m.index);
       }
     } else if (t) {
        if (!--t) {
          a.push(str_copy.slice(s, m.index));
          //found the end match
          if (!g) return a;
        }
     }
   }
   if (g && b.length) {
   //nested matches found
   //slice the string with the index that was
   //saved and keep going
     str_copy = str_copy.slice(b.shift());
     keep_going = true;
   }
}
 while (keep_going || (t && (x.lastIndex = s)));
 return a;
}

var str = '((!%Q1% || %Q2%) || ((%Q3% && %Q4%) || (%Q5% && %Q6%)))';
var res = matchRecursiveRegExp(str, '\\(', '\\)', 'g');
for (var i = 0; i<res.length; i++)
  document.body.innerHTML += "(" + res[i] + ")" + "<br/>";
```