# Regex for parent matched values in nested tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have working in Node.js with javascript.

I want to getting parent div strings using regex.

For Example:

```
<div class="first">
   <p> sample 1</p>
   <div class="second">
        <p>sample 2</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

How to regex for div with class of "first"?  But inside first div, second div also there.

I am trying the following regex

```
 <div class="first">([\s\S]*?)<\/div>
```

I am getting wrong match, starting with first div and end with second div close.

Any idea to find the parent div values.

Thanks in advance.

**Updated:  Agreed.  DOM should solve my problem.  But my html is not well formed and modified.   If i read the document using DOM, it is getting error.  Any alternate way to do.**

Comment: Are you sure you cannot parse the HTML with any DOM parser? Please check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7373003/3832970). *You can use the [npm](http://npmjs.org/) modules [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsdom) and [htmlparser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/htmlparser) to create and parse a DOM in Node.JS.*

Comment: Obligatory link to [bobince's answer on "RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1509264)

Comment: Since regex-based answers for DOM-repated questions are not welcome on SO, I will not post the solution, but you can adapt [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722633/get-all-inner-brackets-parentheses/34723078#34723078) for you current needs.

Comment: If your HTML is so broken that not even a HTML parser can handle it (that is hard to imagine in itself), then throwing regex at it will not exactly help, will it? Fix your HTML and then use proper tools to deal with it.

Comment: @MT0: A counter-post link: [*Oh Yes You Can Use Regexes to Parse HTML!*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/3832970).

Comment: Perhaps you should spin off a question on how to correct the modifications to the XML rather than asking about how to construct a recursive regex? I believe such a question would fall on far more sympathetic ears.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perl Regular Expressions =/= JavaScript Regular Expressions (no named capture groups or recursion). And the post explicitly notes that "while it certainly can be done [...], that doesn’t mean it **should** be."

Comment: @Wiktor Yeah... No. If HTML parsing was as easy as a dozen lines of Perl code, HTML parsers would consist of a dozen lines of Perl code. Funnily enough, they don't. That a Perl guru thinks that *he* can parse HTML with regex is not a big surprise, but that does not make him right. It's always possible to solve a specific, narrow problem with regex, but it's an error in reasoning to generalize from there and say "see, it's possible to parse HTML with regex after all". HTML is not a regular grammar and therefore outside of the domain of what regex can do. It's rather simple, really.

Comment: @Tomalak You know I consider myself excellent at Perl regexes, and I'd totally agree with you. In fact I think Perl's best and brightest do too: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=xml+parser&mode=all There are 940 XML parser modules available in Perl (which I believe is universally accepted as the de facto regex language.) So lets just resay what countless others have said: "Don't parse XML with regexes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is recursion. Javascript's implementation of regexes does not support recursion. In fact the only regexes that do support recursion are Perl 5.10 and Ruby 2.0 [[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)]

What this means for you is that you'll need to do one of the following:

1. Require properly formatted XML input so DOM won't crash (or fix the modification of the XML so that it outputs valid XML)
2. Hand parse this by counting the number of "div"s and subsequent number of "/div"s (this would be a nightmare)
3. Use Perl 5.10+ or Ruby 2.0+ to parse the file and pass results to your Javascript program

It's probably clear that option **1** is the only reasonable option.

Comment: What the OP wants is a HTML parser, not a regex engine that supports recursive expressions.

Comment: @Tomalak I agree, that's why I proposed it as "the only reasonable option."